# Queue of List<T>

Tags: c#, queue

is it ok to declare a Queue of `List<T>` as the following:

```
private static Queue<List<object>> webdata = new Queue<List<object>>();
```

my list of objects normally contains couple datatables and some other objects

- if not, is there a better way to do it?
- if the Queue count was 100 how  do i tell the thread that does the
  Enqueue to stop until the count of the Queue is less than 50?

Comment: What do you mean by "my list of objects normally contains [a] couple [of] databases..."?

Comment: @tvanfosson i mean that there are alot of objects and datatables, and i want to limit my queue to a specific size, hold the Enqueue thread until the Dequeue thread does more processing because it will be taking alot of memory

Comment: Why are you storing these in a queue (or even a list or a queue of lists)?

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a `BlockingCollection` instead.  You can specify a capacity which will ensure there are never more than X elements in the collection at one time.

Comment: @tvanfosson one class gets the data from xml files and html pages ,parses them to datatables, and returns them to a class that does some processing, if you ask why i am not using the parsing/downloading class to do the processing its because i am using alot of free proxies and some requests fail so i have to use a porocessing class, and as expected process got faster but it uses alot of memory so i need to limit my Queue.

Comment: Comments are the wrong forum to talk about it, but why not persist the data rather than store it in memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private static Queue<List<object>> webdata = new Queue<List<object>>();
```

Sure you can declare a data type like that.

> if the Queue count was 100 how do i tell the thread that does the Enqueue to stop until the count of the Queue is less than 50?

This is a perfect job for [TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx).  You can control how many items may be in a processing block before it blocks accepting additional items.

If you have not learned about TPL Dataflow yet, it will require an investment in time to understand the concepts.  However, it is ideally suited for this type of processing and likely well worth the effort.

Comment: i am still learning the basics of c# though, but i will go of this, thanks :)